Why setting Response.Body makes response content empty
I have an endpoint with the following code:
var range = Request.GetTypedHeaders().Range;
var file = new MemoryStream(Enumerable.Range(0, 255).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray());
// Response.Body = file;
return File(file, "application/octet-stream", "{{1.txt}}", null, new EntityTagHeaderValue($"\"1.txt\""), true);

And this is how I send request to it:
var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5100/file") };
request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, 100);
var response = new HttpClient().SendAsync(request).Result;
Debug.WriteLine($"ContentLength: {response.Content.Headers.ContentLength}");
Debug.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage);

The print out is:
ContentLength: 100
Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://localhost:7165/file', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, 
Headers:
{
  Range: bytes=0-100
}

But if I uncomment line with Response.Body = file content length becomes 0. Why?

Don't set the response body explicitly when at the same time you are returning action result using File() method. You can set response explicitly in a action filter or a custom middleware, but why? Just use File() method correctly. See this answer to understand how to do it properly.

This question is similar to: Return file in ASP.Net Core Web API. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I didn't find any document to explain how asp.net core calculate content length when we both set Response.Body manually and set return File at the same time. But based on your test(I had a test in my side with your codes too), it's clearly to see that modifying the response stream interferes with how the framework calculates and sets the Content-Length header. I could just say it's better to not set the response body again when we return File().

in addition, you may need file.Position = 0;  (I seemed to need that when returning File(memorystream...)   When returning a file, it will be streamed so be sure to process the response as such.

var response = new HttpClient().SendAsync(request).Result; <-- Is there a good reason you're not using await here?

I suspect the reason is because you're specifying EntityTagHeaderValue in your response - which isn't matched by the incoming request. The method Microsoft.AspNetCore.Internal.FileResultHelper.SetHeadersAndLog is responsible for setting the Content-Length: header from a FileResult - and it won't set the Content-Length header unless the request's conditions (like E-Tag) match.

Response.Body is an existing stream that you can write to, which will cause the response to be written to the https stream and to the browser. If you replace Response.Body with a random new stream, now there is no connection to the browser.

@JeremyLakeman seems logical to me. Wondering why then it is left with setter.
